# jQuery ul li trees - slideToggle only li with ul child

Tags: html, jquery

I know there are a lot of similar solutions.. This one almost works :)

I have an unsorted list:

```
<ul id="Tree" class="sub-menu">
  <li class="folder">First level
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 1.1</a></li>
      <li class="folder">Second level
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="pathtofile.docx" target="_blank">File 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 2.2</a></li>
          <li class="folder">Tretji nivo
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 3.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="pathtofile.docx" target="_blank">File 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.folder').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('>.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Click on .folder works as desired. The problem is that the slideToggle is triggered on all li elements. So if I click on a li > a element the file is downloaded but the ul is toggled also. I want to prevent toggle when I click on an element that has no direct ul child.

Comment: You could just add `if ($(event.target).hasClass("folder"))` between the 2 lines inside your click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `folder` class to the level text instead of the whole `li` tag :

```js
$('.folder').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Tree" class="sub-menu">
  <li><span class="folder">First level</span>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 1.1</a></li>
      <li><span class="folder">Second level</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="pathtofile.docx" target="_blank">File 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 2.2</a></li>
          <li><span class="folder">Tretji nivo</span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="pathtofile.pdf" target="_blank">File 3.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="pathtofile.docx" target="_blank">File 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```